# Does repository pattern really provides loose coupling in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, .net-6.0, repository-pattern

I am confused on repository pattern, its DI and loose coupling concept. But in any case if I change in my domain classes or interface contracts or data access layer, I need to change code at other projects as well in my solution. Then how it become loosely coupled.

Comment: The repository pattern should abstract away your data persistence mechanism from your business logic code. The data classes are not a part of the repository pattern.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I abstraction is the only benefit in it? What about loose coupling then?

Comment: The loose coupling comes from the fact that your code only depends upon the interface not any specific implementation and the details behind that interface. This means that during DI it's possible to substitute in any implementation of that interface without any side-effects for the rest of the program. Unfortunately if your models change then your implementation also have to change.

Comment: @phuzi re: Unfortunately if your models change then your implementation also have to change. --> exactly my point is. It means its not loosely coupled.

Comment: The repository pattern doesn't involve you models, it only involves your persistence. There's no design pattern that can save you from the need to change the database table when the model changes.

Comment: @learningdotnet the loose coupling is about not tying your program to a specific implementation and being free to swap and change as necessary. You could have one implementation of your repository using SQLite and another version using Azure Cosmos DB but the rest of your application (apart from DI configuration) should neither know or care which one is being used. There's no way to avoid changes to either implementation if the structure of models being stored changes unless you don't mind errors or potential data loss.

Comment: @phuzi what does mean by  --> You could have one implementation of your repository using SQLite and another version using Azure Cosmos DB but the rest of your application (apart from DI configuration) should neither know or care which one is being used. This I can achieve without any specific repository or any design pattern. I am still confused. Can you explain with any real time example please.

Comment: _"This I can achieve without any specific repository or any design pattern"_ Yes, you can and if you do it in a way that you can swap out the implementations at will without having to change anything else then it's loosely coupled. Just because you haven't gone out of your way to implement a specific pattern doesn't mean you didn't use a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, repository pattern works only if you change implementation of repository interface(I.e from ef to dapper and vice versa or smth like this). But if you change your models, it won’t work. Also if you change your interface methods, repository class stops to correspond them, and you must fix it.